# Azure caching error?

Tags: azure, azure-caching

I have an azure web role deployed and my error logs tell me that I am getting the error :

ErrorCode:SubStatus:The connection was terminated, possibly due to server or network problems or serialized Object size is greater than MaxBufferSize on server. Result of the request is unknown.. Additional Information : The client was trying to communicate with the server: net.tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20003.

What is causing this error?

Where is the MaxBufferSize specified?

How do I correct this issue?

Comment: How big of an object are you trying to cache?

Comment: This may help :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991166/exception-while-using-windows-azure-caching-no-such-host-is-known

Answer (score 0):

If you are using azure managed cache, maximum allowed object size is 8 MB. You will get this error if you are trying to put an object bigger than that..