# Configure azure shared cache locally and on the cloud

Tags: c#, azure, shared-cache

I'm at a complete loss with getting the shared caching to work.

Locally, I've got an mvc4 site running and I created a cloud project from this.  I enabled caching on the role and set this to be co-located.  All fine so far.

I added the [Windows Azure Caching](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching/2.1.0.0) 2.1 package from NuGet which installed the relevant libraries and also updated my web config:

**configSections**:

```
<section name="dataCacheClients" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientsSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
<section name="cacheDiagnostics" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon.DiagnosticsConfigurationSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
```

**config**:

```
<dataCacheClients>
<dataCacheClient name="default">
  <!--To use the in-role flavor of Windows Azure Caching, set identifier to be the cache cluster role name -->
  <!--To use the Windows Azure Caching Service, set identifier to be the endpoint of the cache cluster -->
  <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="" />
  <!--<localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" objectCount="100000" ttlValue="300" />-->
  <!--Use this section to specify security settings for connecting to your cache. This section is not required if your cache is hosted on a role that is a part of your cloud service. -->
  <!--<securityProperties mode="Message" sslEnabled="false">
    <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="[Authentication Key]" />
  </securityProperties>-->
</dataCacheClient>
```

When I follow the instructions and add the role name to `identifer` attribute on the `autoDiscover` element and run the app, it seems to just hang (I'm assuming failing) on this:

```
_cache = new DataCache("default");
```

I have the storage emulator running and the site debugging from the compute emulator.   I just can't seem to get the site to work configured to use the azure cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please make sure that you're using SDK version 2.1. **Caching 2.1 package will only work with the latest version of SDK** (see the screenshot below). You may want to check out this thread here: [Exception while using Windows Azure Caching : No such host is known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991166/exception-while-using-windows-azure-caching-no-such-host-is-known)

[image]

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar.  I found the updated sdk [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/) and installed the 2.1 version - goodbye freeze, hello web page. I must have just missed the boat for 2.1 as I've only just been starting out with Azure.